# Change the colors of a qplot based on the value of a row

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a *qplot*, where any row with the value `"setosa"` in the column `"Species"` is colored red.

Is there a very simple way to add this to the *qplot* below?

```
df <- iris

qplot(df$Species, df$Petal.Length)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *ggplot* instead of *qplot* for more control, example:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- iris
df$myCol <- ifelse(df$Species == "setosa", "red", "black")

qplot(Species, Petal.Length, data = df, col = myCol)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(Species, Petal.Length, col = myCol)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

Another option with legend:

```
df$myGroup <- ifelse(df$Species == "setosa", "setosa", "not setosa")

ggplot(df, aes(Species, Petal.Length, col = myGroup)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("setosa" = "red", "not setosa" = "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I should move away from qplot and start using the ggplot command instead, so thanks for including those examples too!